# Spring data one to many mapping bi-directional

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, one-to-many

I'm working with a legacy System and have to implement some features which is similar to below problem.
Tables are Manager and Department where a manager can have more than one department but a department does have only one manager.

Manager

- manager_id. -> primary key.
- manager_name.
- department_id.

Department

- dept_id. -> primary key.
- dept_name.
- manager_id. This is a reference to Manager's table.

There's no foreign key or other constraint on those tables.

My implementation was,
 One to Many bi-directional since I do have manager_id in Department table as well.

My code snippet:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Manager_T")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Manager {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "manager_id", sequenceName = "manager_id", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "manager_id")
        @Column(name="manager_id")
        private Long managerId;

        @Column(name="manager_name")
        private String managerName;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "managers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JsonManagedReference
        private Set<Department> departments;
```

}

Department Entity:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Department_T")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public class Department {

        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "dept_id", sequenceName = "dept_id", allocationSize = 1)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "dept_id")
        @Column(name="dept_id")
        private Long deptId;

        @Column(name="dept_name")
        private String deptName;

        // Only those departments for which manager exists.
        @ManyToOne(optional=false)
        @JoinColumn(name="manager_id")
        @JsonBackReference
        private Manager manager;
```

}

Output: For ManagerController.

- Get:
   /managers: returns managers along with list of departments for each manager.
   /managers/id: returns a manager with its department list.
- Delete:
   /managers: deletes the Manager and all it's associated dept.
- Post(Add):

  1. Except Manager id which is generated sequentially everything else is set to null. When I looked into the logs it seems, it first calls insert and then update on the Manager table. I guess update is causing the null behavior to all its properties. Also, Department table is not getting inserted.
     JSON Data which I passed for insertion was similar to:

     {
         "managerName": "John"
         [{
             "deptName": "Sales"
         }]
     }

Note: There was some problem with my Controller which didn't pass the value accurately which caused the null behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change departments initialisation in Manager, assign an empty HashSet.

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "managers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Department> departments=new HashSet<Department>();
```

Comment: Null behavior was caused because of some problem in my Controller. But I guess it was also an issue and now it works like a charm.